# EmberJS: How to check if a component exists (inside another component)?

Tags: ember.js, components

My goal is to resolve to a generic component is the component doesn't exists. It managed to do it like this:

```
  // app/components/dynamic-widget.js
  ...
  widgetName: function() {
    var name = this.get('config.name');
    if (!this.container.resolve('component:'+name)) {
       name = 'generic-widget';
    }
    return name;
  }.property('config.name')
  ...
```

Then in `app/templates/components/dynamic-widget.hbs`:

```
    {{component widgetName}}
```

Then, I could use my `dynamic-component` like this:

```
    {{dynamic-widget 'foo-widget'}}
```

If `foo-widget` is not implemented, it fallback into `generic-widget`.

But since EmberJS 1.11, resolving a component from a component's container is deprecated:

```
DEPRECATION: resolve should be called on the registry instead of the container
```

So my question is, how can I check if a component actually exists without using `this.container.resolve` ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically determine existence of Ember component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795611/dynamically-determine-existence-of-ember-component)

Answer (score 0):

Does this.container.registery.resolve work?

Looking at the code in git https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/5fd2d035b30aa9ebfe73de824b3b283ec8e589cc/packages/container/lib/registry.js

Looks like you may also be able to use this.container.registery.has

Comment: Thanks for your anwer but in a component, this.container.registry is undefined: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'has' of undefined`... I also try to access to the registry directly from the component (`this.registry`) without luck...

Comment: Looks like it's this.container._registry.  It maybe worth filing an issue with ember on github to have them clarify the deprecation warning.