# Dynamically determine existence of Ember component?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I was looking through the ember-htmlbars package and discovered this util for determining if a component is available? https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-htmlbars/lib/utils/is-component.js

Is there any way to use this from my app? I'm building a dashboard-type interface and some of the dashboard widgets have optional actions. In essence I'd like to do something like:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    {{component model.displayComponent model=model}}
  </div>
  {{#if isComponent(model.actionComponent) }} <!-- this would be a property -->
    <div class="panel-footer">
      {{component model.actionComponent model=model}}
    </div>
  {{/if}}
</div>
```

My fallback is to put a blank action component for each of my widgets that don't have one, but it would be cleaner to be able to check to see if they exist first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create helper `is-component`

```
export default Ember.Helper.extend({
  compute([name]) {
    return this.container.registry.has('component:' + name);
  }
})
```

and use it like  `{{#if (is-component model.actionComponent) }}`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I will research the container.registry and figure out what you're doing here.

Comment: container is where singleton instances of objects are cached and registry is where all classes/factories are stored :)