# Dynamically determine existence of template only Ember glimmer component?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, glimmer.js

I know that to dynamically determine the existence of a component on Ember we can use the solutions explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34798685/3695939) or [here](https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/existing-component-check-in-js-file/9624).

We have a helper that uses `.hasRegistration('component:${component}')`

This also works for Glimmer components as long as there is a .js file defined, but it doesn't work for [template-only Glimmer components](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/upgrading/current-edition/glimmer-components/#toc_template-only-components). The component doesn't seem to be registered in that case.

Does anyone know a solution that would work for template-only glimmer components too?

Comment: What ember source version are you using?

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli 3.26.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a demo for you over on stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-k7htnb?file=app%2Fcomponents%2Fdemo.hbs

```
{
  "component:template-only": true,
  "template:template-only": false
}
```

here is the code showing that what you're doing works in Ember 3.28:

```
<pre>{{this.format this.results}}</pre>
```

```
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { tracked } from '@glimmer/tracking';
import { getOwner } from '@ember/application';

export default class Demo extends Component {
  format = (data) => JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);

  @tracked name = 'template-only';

  get results() {
    let owner = getOwner(this);
    let name = this.name;

    return {
      [`component:${name}`]: owner.hasRegistration(`component:${name}`),
      // added this for curiosity
      [`template:${name}`]: owner.hasRegistration(`template:${name}`),
    };
  }
}
```

Now, if I change the ember-source to 3.26.1, it's the same.

Maybe there is a slight code mismatch between what you're doing and what this demo is doing?

Comment: Thanks for the demo. On our case `template-only.hbs` is under the `templates/components` folder. Could that be why it isn't recognized?

Comment: yup, exactly -- that'll need to be moved to the new location. There is a tool to help with that if you have a lot of those: https://github.com/ember-codemods/ember-component-template-colocation-migrator